# Comparing amino acids in Mathematica nutrition data

Tags: dataset, entity

Essential amino acids for lentils and barley can compensate each other: what the one does not have, the other has. How can I find that in the nutrition database?
I can find such in old tables but can it be done within Mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

It appears `"Barley"` is a `"FoodType"` in the database.
If we do `Entity["FoodType", "Barley"]["Foods"]` we can see the foods it appears in. In this case I'm going to use `"BarleyHulled::4m2q6"`:

```
barleyAAs = Entity["Food", "BarleyHulled::4m2q6"]["AvailableAminoAcids"]

(** RETURNS:
{Entity["Nutrient", "Alanine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Arginine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "AsparticAcid"], Entity["Nutrient", "Cystine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "GlutamicAcid"], Entity["Nutrient", "Glycine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Histidine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Isoleucine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Leucine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Lysine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Methionine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Phenylalanine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Proline"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Serine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Threonine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Tryptophan"], Entity["Nutrient", "Tyrosine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Valine"]}
**)
```

The same can be done for `Entity["FoodType", "Lentil"]`.

and from `Entity["FoodType", "Lentil"]["Foods"]` I will choose `"LentilsRaw::y7234"`:

```
lentilAAs= Entity["Food", "LentilsRaw::y7234"]["AvailableAminoAcids"]

(** RETURNS:
{Entity["Nutrient", "Alanine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Arginine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "AsparticAcid"], Entity["Nutrient", "Cystine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "GlutamicAcid"], Entity["Nutrient", "Glycine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Histidine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Isoleucine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Leucine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Lysine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Methionine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Phenylalanine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Proline"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Serine"], Entity["Nutrient", "Threonine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Tryptophan"], Entity["Nutrient", "Tyrosine"], 
 Entity["Nutrient", "Valine"]}
**)
```

So according to the *Mathematica* database they have the same amino acids.

```
Entity["Food", "LentilsRaw::y7234"]["AvailableAminoAcids"] ==
 Entity["Food", "BarleyHulled::4m2q6"]["AvailableAminoAcids"]
(* RETURNS: True *)
```

If we use `"BarleyFlourOrMeal::y4474"` instead, then we get:

```
Complement[
 Entity["Food", "BarleyFlourOrMeal::y4474"]["AvailableAminoAcids"],
 Entity["Food", "LentilsRaw::y7234"]["AvailableAminoAcids"]
 ]

(** RETURNS: Entity["Nutrient", "Betaine"] **)
```

Comment: Hello Flinty.The food database was so confusing to me! Now I can better ask. I want the contents of barley and lentils in a table and then compare.  Your code is a nice beginning. Thanks.